# Внесение изменений в ивенты Google-календаря

Tags: api, google-calendar

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь сделать изменения в ивенты гугл календаря и отправить изменения на сервер для сохранения с помощью запроса

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
```

На сайте гугла делаю тестовый запрос - все получается, но там строка вида

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/47g1e5jicusrc55e9n18po1198%40group.calendar.google.com/events/6sri99j1uvvqhls37gqoi9d4p4?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

У меня постоянно ошибка 403.

**Вопрос:** что это такое - `?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, тебе сюда: https://console.developers.google.com/project
Cлева API & Auth.
Тут ты зарегистрируешь свое приложение и получишь заветный ключик )

// В документации подробно все расписано.